# Adding a Simple Subtraction Formula to a Case When Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I'm writing a sql script where I'd like to add a subtraction formula to the script. My problem is that when I add this CASE STATEMENT my script will not run. I read that you need to add paranetheses around the formula, which I did, and when I do this without the CASE WHEN it will work great. Can you just not use formulas within a case statement?

In my statement below, I have a column, TotalWeightLoss, where its a cumulative total weight lost by a person. So what I am trying to do is see the monthly weight lost instead of a cumulative total.

```
SELECT *
       ,case when rownmbr=1 then TotalWeightLoss else (TotalWeightLoss - LAG(TotalWeightLoss) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY ProcessDate, ProcessDate)) AS AmountLost
from cte;"))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Your case *expression* is missing an `end`

Comment: God, I'm really dumb. Thank you! Sorry for the dumb question and looking over something as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the missing END: Assuming that `rownmbr` is based on a ROW_NUMBER calculation this can be simplified to

```
TotalWeightLoss
 - LAG(TotalWeightLoss,1,0) -- LAG supports a default for a missing value 
   OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber 
         ORDER BY ProcessDate, ProcessDate) AS AmountLost
```